# Does commiting to one file revoke all approvals provided to github pull request or not?

Tags: github, github-codereviews, github-codeowners

I have a pull request that makes changes to multiple files and codeowners of those files are different.
Example:

File_1 has codeowners X,Y,Z
File_2 has codeowners A,B

Initially X,Y and Z approved the PR but A and B suggested a change.

So, if I commit a change to File_2 will the approval of X,Y and Z be lost as well.
(If i push a change to File_1 the approval does get lost)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is expected behavior, as it is stated in the branch protection policy. This goes for all approvals, even

```
Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed
```

CODEOWNERS are only used for adding the initial approvers as 'required' and don't do anything extra after that.